# How to project specific fields from subdocument baed on value of field from same document in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

Given a document with a subdocument from a `$lookup` aggregation, I want to project a specific field form the subdocument based on the field of the `$$ROOT` document. Example:

```
{
   "date": "2023-08-20",
   "code": "USD",
   "exchange_rates": {
      "USD": 1.01,
      "EUR": 2.01,
      "CNY": 3.01
   }
}
```

I want to get:

```
{
   "date": "2023-08-20",
   "exchange_rate": 1.01
}
```

This subdocument came from a `$lookup` operation, so maybe I can put the project (or any other command) directly inside the `pipeline` argument from this aggregation directly.

Comment: what are ur 2 collections look like

Comment: One has the root document structure (date and code fields) and the other has the exchange rates (USD, EUR and CNY fields) and a date field, which I use to look up.

Answer (score 1):

One option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
//{$lookup...}
  {$project: {
      _id: 0,
      date: 1,
      exchange_rate: {$getField: {
          input: {$first: {$filter: {
                input: {$objectToArray: "$exchange_rates"},
                cond: {$eq: ["$$this.k", "$code"]}
          }}},
          field: "v"
      }}
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-iD_jyjw1ru)

Answer (score 0):

Given I have the following collections:

- `one`, which contains:

  ```
  {
      "date": "2023-08-20",
      "code": "USD",
      "exchange_rates": {
         "USD": 1.01,
         "EUR": 2.01,
         "CNY": 3.01
      }
   }
  ```
- `two`, which contains: `{date: '2023-08-20'}`

I can use the following pipeline to get the desired result from collection one, based on the date. I used $addFields to override the exchange_rates to USD.

```
db.two.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'one',
                as: 'exchange',
                let: {date: '$date'},
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: ['$date', '$$date']
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $addFields: {
                            "exchange_rates": "$exchange_rates.USD"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        { $unwind: "$exchange"},
        { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$exchange" } },
        { $project: {_id: 0, date: 1, "exchange_rates": 1} }
    ]
)
```

Will result in:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2023-08-20",
    "exchange_rates": 1.01
  }
]
```